# How to start vm from different subscription using Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have three subscription in same tenant say Sub1, Sub2 and Sub3. I have created **Automation Account is in Sub1** and **my VMs are in Sub3**. (Cant create Automation account in Sub3 due to some restrictions). I want to write a powershell script which will start Sub3 VM.

When I ran **Get-AzureRmSubscription** it is giving me only my current subscription i.e. Sub1
My azure automation script is as below -

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Get-AzureRmSubscription

 # $context = Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId {subId}
# Set-AzureRmContext $context
# Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceName" -Name "VMName"
```

Can you please guide how can I go this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your subscriptions are in the same tenant, you can directly assign an Azure RABC role to your Azure Automation connection(service principal ) in your **Sub3**. Then you can manage Azure resource in **Sub3**

For example

1. Get the Connection Application ID
   [image]
2. Assign role

```
Connect-AzAccount
 $sp=Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId < the appId you copy>
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId <the id of sub3>
#assign Contributor role to the connection at subsciprion level
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $sp.id -RoleDefinitionName Contributor
```

3. Test

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the lead Jim. I have added and modified required fields from the script you provided. Getting error as "Connect-AzAccount : The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:2 char:1" Tried by changing Connect-AzAccount to Connect-AzureRmAccount but still same error.

Comment: @Oxygen please run the step 2 script on your local machine with the account which is the owner of your sub3.

Comment: This helped @Jim. Thank you so much